# Unknown number of arguments of method in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

For example I have a class `PartE` such:

```
public class PartE implements Part
{
  protected String method = "getIndex" ;

  protected String getIndex ( double dummy,int dummyInt,String dummyString )
  {
    return "E" ;
  }
}
```

In this code I should invoke a method with unknown number of arguments. In this case it is `getIndex(double,int,String)`.

It can be in this way:

```
getIndex()
getIndex(int)
getIndex(boolean,int)
getIndex(int,double,boolean)
```

So whatever combination of arguments, I have done this but it seems that I am doing error in `params[i].newInstance()` because it returns not proper thing for instantiation. That's why I am taking `InstantiationException`. I got stuck what can I do?

```
Class c1 = null;

try {
    c1 = Class.forName( "PartE" );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {}

Object obj = null;
obj = c1.newInstance();

Method [] methods = c1.getDeclaredMethods();

for(Method m:methods)
  {
      m.setAccessible(true);

      Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
      Object[] paramObjects = new Object[params.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) 
      {
          paramObjects[i] = params[i].newInstance();
      }

      try {
         System.out.println(m.invoke(obj, paramObjects));  
      } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {}
```

Comment: *"In this code I should invoke a method with unknown number of arguments."* Why? When would that possibly come up? Methods have arguments *for a reason*. You can't just feed them random values and expect valid results.

Comment: It is the requirement of homework. Instructor wants students to write very flexible and dynamic reflection code. He will test our code by changing inside of class structure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, in Java a method name might have multiple declarations.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Yes, it might; that's also completely irrelevant.

Comment: @NYU, can you debug your code and tell us what class did you try to instantiate when you failed?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, if there are multiple declarations for the same method name, one might need to dynamically load a saved setup and re-instantiate the objects, re-call the methods.

Comment: @NYU Reflection cannot be very flexible. It has certain limitations, in your case the arguments may not contain the default constructor in what case you will have to somehow provide it with values even if that is dummies, but that will lead to a recursive operation that i consider pointless. I don't understand why you need to call methods with no-real-value arguments though. Also something i noticed that is important, Do not leave exceptions unhandled while still working on this project! There is a reason why they are thrown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the possibility that the class you need doesn't support a no-params constructor, since `newInstance` requires one but neither [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#constructor.summary) nor [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#constructor.summary) has one. That means you'll need to add branching within your loop over the parameter types, to at least handle `Integer` and `Double`. Presumably the assignment tells you what values you should use (or that it doesn't matter what values you use) for those arguments, since you can't pass `null` (you'll get an unboxing error if you use `null` since the method expects `int` and `double`, not `Integer` and `Double`) and they don't have a no-params constructor.

This answer is intentionally given as prose rather than code because the point of the assignment, presumably, is to learn to write that code. :-)